# Image Resize when rotate using UIRotationGestureRecognizer in iphone application

Tags: iphone

I add One ScrollView in that i put image when i resize image using viewForZoomingInScrollView
after that i Rotate image using UIRotationGestureRecognizer at that time image getting resize automatically so any solution for this problem.

here i put code for zoom and rotate:
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return Photo;
}

/*In response to a rotation gesture, show the image view at the rotation given by the recognizer, then make it fade out in place while rotating back to horizontal.
*/
- (void)handleRotationFrom:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation([recognizer rotation]);
Photo.transform = transform;
```

}

Comment: so what is the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement class EditImageView

handle touch over there for tracking touch.